# Python - is there any way to organize a group of yields in sub function to yield outside the main function?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have a newbie question for python gurus.

I have function A that hold a lot of repeated yield-actions like so:

```
yield a
yield b
yield c
```

so it looks like:

```
def funA():
    …
   yield a
   yield b
   yield c
    …
   yield a
   yield b
   yield c
    …
   yield a
   yield b
   yield c
```

Is there any way to put all repeated yields in function and do something like that?:

```
def funA():
    …
   yield funB()
    …
   yield funB()
    …
   yield funB()
```

## Update

```
yield a
yield b
yield c
```

It's just an example but in a real application its more complex sequence of yields that repeat more then once in main generator (so it's not question about organizing yields) but about sub-generators. So I'd like to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Why are you doing this? That sounds pretty terrible. You really shouldn't have more than 1 yield in a single function. Otherwise you're kind of defeating the point.

Comment: I suspect itertools is the way to go here.

Comment: While it is possible to do this, it sounds like what you really need is a `yield` in a loop.

Comment: @Falmarri can you share any information about why more then 1 yield in  a single function is the bad practice?

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets: It's not that more than 1 yield is in and of itself bad practice. It just indicates that your overall design is flawed.

Comment: @Falmarri Why? Can you give more details? Or share links to articles or books about this problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using the latest and greatest `python` (>= 3.3), there's the [`yield from`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) construct.

```
yield from funB()
```

It does exactly what you want: you can invoke a function as a sub-generator, and yield back everything it yields to you.

If you're using an earlier version of `python`, then I'm afraid you'll have to do it manually:

```
for x in funB(): yield x
```

If you have a dynamic set of sub-generators, you can do this:

```
funs = [funA, funB, funC]

for fun in funs:
    for item in fun():
        yield item
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! It is exactly what I need, sadly I use 2.7 version.

Comment: So Is it possible to make such a conclusion: if we have python < 3.3. It's better not to do any sub-generators and just repeat yields? So left function as it was before

Comment: On the contrary, I think your idea was good. An endless stream of `yield` statements is hard on the eyes. See my edit above for a possible grouping technique

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.chain` is the function you're looking for

```
import itertools

def funA():
    for x in range(10):
        yield x

def funB():
    for x in range(10,20):
        yield x

def funC():
    for x in range(20,30):
        yield x

def funs():
    for x in itertools.chain(funA(), funB(), funC()):
        yield x

print [x for x in funs()]
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```